# PDO won't give results

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So, I've switched from mysql_* to PDO today and am trying to get it running, but somehow I get zero results.

My Statement is as follows:

```
$serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
    $db = $serverConnector->connectToServer();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_USERS . "` WHERE `" . USER_NICKNAME . "` =:user_nickname OR `" . USER_EMAIL . "` =:user_email;");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_nickname' => "'".$name_or_email."'", ':user_email' => "'".$name_or_email."'"));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $this->id = $row[USER_ID];
        $this->joined = $row[USER_JOINED];
        ...
    }
    $db = null;
```

I've tried executing this statement as pure SQL on Xampp. Worked there. Doesn't work here though. I've tripple checked all parameters im passing and everything is correct. Somehow the program won't enter the while loop at all. ServerConnector simply connects to the Database via PDO and returns an PDO Database Object to $db.

Thanks

EDIT: Well, I'm using the newest Xampp with PHP 5.4.7. PDO Should be enabled by default. Checked the php.ini file myself and it was enabled in there as well

EDIT: Here's my ServerConnector class. Errorreporting enabled. Though I won't get any :/

```
class ServerConnector {

    public function connectToServer(){
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME . ';charset=UTF-8', 
                       DATABASE_USERNAME, 
                       DATABASE_PASSWORD, 
                       array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        return $db;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not include the trailing semi-colon in your SQL statement.

Comment: Alright. thought it was "good style". Doesn't do the trick though

Comment: @crush, really?  I am in the habit of always terminating them with a semi-colon.

Comment: PHP specifically says not to include the `;` in your SQL statement in their documentation. If you are including multiple statements in a single query, then I suppose it would be okay. It's not going to mess up your query - it's just recommended that you do not include it.

Comment: What's the point in having table fields in PHP constants? Why can't you just write `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_nickname=:user_nickname"`? Okay, I can understand a table name. But column names?

Comment: Added [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) reference specifying that SQL statement should not end in `;`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I just find it easier to have them in constants, so I won't do mistakes while creating a new DB and then accessing data. This way I create the constants once and use them all the time, without the need of remembering how they're actually called in the DB

Comment: btw, mysql charset is spelled `utf8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, checked my DB output with print_r($row) and found out I'm having a two dimensional array here that my program doesn't go through. Means I'm having all my info on $row[0][KEY] and not on $row[key].

Fixed :)

EDIT: Well, I'll also post my code. Had it the exact same way two hours ago, but it didn't work. Don't ask me why -.-'Works like this:

```
function receiveUserData( $name_or_email ) {

    $serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
    $db = $serverConnector->connectToServer();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_USERS . "` WHERE `" . USER_NICKNAME . "` =:user_nickname OR `" . USER_EMAIL . "` =:user_email");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_nickname' => $name_or_email, ':user_email' => $name_or_email));

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    $this->user_id = $row[USER_ID];
    $this->user_joined = $row[USER_JOINED];
    $this->user_last_seen = $row[USER_LAST_SEEN];
    $this->user_salt = $row[USER_SALT];
    $this->user_nickname = $row[USER_NICKNAME];
    $this->user_name = $row[USER_NAME];
    $this->user_last_name = $row[USER_LAST_NAME];
    $this->user_email = $row[USER_EMAIL];
    $this->user_password = $row[USER_PASSWORD];
    $this->user_save_password = $row[USER_SAVE_PASSWORD];

    $db = null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You dont have to quote with a prepared statement:

```
$serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
    $db = $serverConnector->connectToServer();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_USERS . "` WHERE `" . USER_NICKNAME . "` =:user_nickname OR `" . USER_EMAIL . "` =:user_email;");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_nickname' => $name_or_email, ':user_email' => $name_or_email));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $this->id = $row[USER_ID];
        $this->joined = $row[USER_JOINED];
        ...
    }
    $db = null;
```

Comment: Yeah, was an attempt to fix my problem, but it didn't work out :/ Thanks for the advice anyhow

Comment: @justbasti Are you sure the constants (TABLE_USERS, USER_ID etc) and the variables are set, and have the value you want?

Comment: Yes, everything :/ Got my own Settings file with all those constants inside and tripple checked them aswell. Included them as often as possible, so I wouldn't miss it anywhere, even if its senseless ^^

Comment: Check crush's answer, I overlooked that one, and changed my answer

Answer (score 2):

Building on what was said above about not needing to add quotations in the `execute()`:

```
$serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
$db = $serverConnector->connectToServer();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_USERS . "` WHERE `" . USER_NICKNAME . "` =:user_nickname OR `" . USER_EMAIL . "` =:user_email;");
$stmt->execute(array(':user_nickname' => $name_or_email, ':user_email' => $name_or_email));
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->id = $row[USER_ID];
    $this->joined = $row[USER_JOINED];
    ...
}
$db = null;
```

The following doesn't need to be in a while loop:

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll()
```

This doesn't need to be in a while loop. It returns the entire recordset as an array, so you will only get a single iteration out of that loop.

You can either change that to `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` or not use the while loop, and iterate over `$row`.

Comment: I also wanted to add that you can do use [PDOStatement::fetchObject()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) to fetch directly into whatever object `$this` represents if the column names are the same as your object's properties. It would return a new instance of that class, though.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give it a try as soon as I fixed this bug :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks critical thing: an error message

It seems that the following is the most demanded answer to PDO questions:

Your **real** problem is lack of error reporting. So

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to be notified of all PHP errors like misspelled constants

```
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

in your server connector to be notified of PDO errors

*After* getting the actual error message you can either solve it yourself or ask for assistance here

Comment: Thanks, already done that. I'll just edit the ServerConnector class to my post